# How to not overlap the textviews?

Tags: android

Is there any codes which won't overlap the textviews? Because if my name is long, it will overlap the Textview, Name:

Name: Abcdefghijk

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Name:"
            android:textSize="20px" />

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:textSize="20px"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:textSize="20px"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lblName"
        android:textSize="20px"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**android:ellipsize="marquee"** cuts the text to the available space

Comment: but my question is to be able to show. Even if it cuts the text, the remaining text should appear at the next following line

Answer (score 0):

can use `android:freezesText` or `android:layout_toRightOf` property of textview see [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: you mean android:freezesText="true" ?